# speech to text javascript to recognize medical dictionary

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I've been searching for a good javascript API to recognize medical words quickly. I used webspeech API which is pretty good at recognizing words but it seems to fail at recognizing medical words real quick like adult echo, heart rate. 
I've also used pocketsphinx.js which again works only for a non-medical words. can i include a medical dictionary to use pocketsphinx.js ? I needed an open-source javascript API.

Also wanted to know whether I can get a free-trail for nuance speech recognition which is apt for medical applications.

Please suggest a good way of going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal favorite speech-to-text JS library: [Wit AI](https://wit.ai/).

You teach it what it needs to recognize. By repeating yourself over and over again, it's accuracy for recognition increases.

Comment: Let me know if you need help. I have code examples on github if you need for reference.

Comment: @user3905315 how goes?